Analog multi part story about humans of present suddenly confronted with humans of the future fleeing
Multi part, sci fi mag in 70s or early 80s, polite people start streaming out of time portals leading from the future. There are aliens exterminating them (recreational hunting)but through time travel they hope to escape. Aliens are so naturally deadly that they don't really need any technology or weapons other than their spaceships. Although the portals are guarded at the far end they asked the present day authorities to set up artillery in front of the portal exits in case they lose control the entrances. One of the aliens (kind of dinosaur like) gets through one of the portals in the first part and there I am left hanging...

I think you're thinking of Simak's Our Children's Children - from Worlds of If in May-June and July-August issues from 1973.
This review says:

The premises are simple enough; about five hundred years from now the
earth is attacked by an alien hunter race - a race that lives to hunt
and kill. They are having a lot of fun with the human race, which has
become pacifistic and has lost almost all their knowledge of war
(yeah, right!). We are getting our asses kicked (or arses if you
like). Luckily the people of the future have found an other dimension,
where time flows backwards making time travel to the past possible. So
the entire population of future earth escapes in to the past - and
suddenly we have two billion (2.000.000.000) refugees.
So the race is on, to get the refugees further back in time, before
the world economy gets ruined and our food stores are depleted.
Oh, yes and as an added bonus, a few of the aliens manage to get
through the time tunnels as well.

which seems like a good match.

So what happens next?

I never read it so I don't know.  Perhaps all of humanity was wiped out - in one of the cheerful endings that Simak was known for :)
